# Python Module Only Found With .py

Tags: python, module

I am attempting to make a command line python tool to locate IP addresses.  I am using the pygeoip library. When I have the file as filename.py, and I run it using

```
python filename.py -options
```

it works fine.  But when I rename it to just filename (no .py) and add

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

To the top of the top of the file, the pygeoip module can no longer be found.  I have chmoded the file properly.

Anyone come across this before?

Comment: This is linux? what does `which python` say? Its common for the shebang to be `#!/usr/bin/env python` to get the current environments python.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, I just figured it out.  For redistribution purposes should I stick with #!/usr/bin/python, and just use my path for testing?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python` is far superior in my opinion. You don't make assumptions about the target environment that way. However, some things like setuptools rewrite the shebang during install - a thing i find annoying but others think its great.

Comment: Yeah ok thanks, I think ill stick with user/bin/env

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that /usr/bin/python is not the same python where pygeiop is installed. The shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

tells the shell to execute the script with the program given. If you change it to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

the shell will search the PATH for a python and use it. If your "real" python is first on the path, it is run. You could use virtualenv, or even just add your favorite python to the front of PATH to control what is executed.

For deployment, /usr/bin/env is superior because then you don't have to worry about where the user installed python. It could be in /usr/local/bin or who knows where, and the shell will find it.